# Can we Open Multiple DrawerLayout in One Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Can we open multiple DrawerLayout in one activity.
i mean when open on one DrawerLayout and onclick on item open another drawerlayout.
(Nested Drawer layout).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using `Fragments`.

From the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` you can include a button somewhere that has `OnClickListener`where in you put this code .

***open a new Drawer :***

```
//For me a better way in avoiding a `null pointer` in getting the DrawerLayout
   final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //Opens the Drawer
                drawer.openDrawer(Your View, Usually a ListView);
            }

                return false;
        });
```

***And close Drawer :***

```
drawer.closeDrawer(Your View, Usually a ListView);
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: thanks to reply,i have understand but please share helping links like tutorial or source which i can implement.

Comment: I hope this step by step tutorial will help you https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-example.html

Comment: ! i want to add expendablelistview not simple listview which contain different child layout.first child contain two button and on button click open another drawerlayout.i cannot find any solution,because when i register button click in getChildView of BaseExpandableListAdapter then two task i want done 1) hide first drawerlayout and 2) open new drawerlayout with custom view.please any solution snuggest for me,i found this tutorial but they not contain on button and nested drawerlayout..http://www.techiecommunity.net/Android/Android-ExpandableListView-Layout-Example